# Display contents of a hash if value exists

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
req = {
  "count" => 50100,
  "results" => [
    {"listing_id" => 615929315, "state" => "active", "user_id" => 140604756, "category_id" => 69150367}, 
    {"listing_id" => 615929311, "state" => "active", "user_id" => 152528025, "category_id" => 69150367}
  ]
}
```

I want to find and display the entire internal hash if a particular `user_id` exists. I can find it:

```
req["results"][0].select{|key, value| value == 152528025}
# => {"user_id" => 152528025}
```

How do I then display this entire (nested) hash?

```
{"listing_id" => 615929311, "state" => "active", "user_id" => 152528025, "category_id" => 69150367}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
req["results"].select{|x| x["user_id"] == 152528025}
```

Comment: If there is at most 1 result for a given `user_id` then you should replace `select` with `find`. This will return the first hash that matches instead of an array, and avoids searching the rest of the array once a match is found.